# AdMob ads not showing in android layout

Tags: android, admob

I have an android app and I want add adMob ads. I have below codes, when I listen adView with onReceiveAd()  the ads comes but not shows in layout  Any idea?

```
adsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ads);
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, Constants.adMobId);
adsLayout.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest().setTesting(true));
```

I have also internet permission and admob configchanges in manifest

adsLayout is

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adsLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >
</LinearLayout>
```

I pass publisherId with below code

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, Constants.adMobKey);
```

Comment: What are the parameters of linearLayout and where you gived admob ad Id ? (in layout or in code )

Comment: @rahulkapoor I add layout to question and I give admob id to adView constructor

Comment: What you getting in logcat ?

Comment: adsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ads); must be adsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adsLayout);

Comment: And do not use a deprecated `setTesting(true)` use `AdRequest adR = new AdRequest();adR.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);`if it is on a emulator, your device id if it is on your device.

Comment: @AlexBcn you are right. On logcat also says add request.addTestDevice("E91843247A1DD90271BC417235E9B5EE"); Now its showing.  thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this step:

#### Set Permission to manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

#### Put this code into onCreate Method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
    // Ad Code
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.setTesting(true);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    // End Ad Code
}
```

#### Before Publishing setTestDevice to test

```
    AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] {AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR});
    AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.requestFreshAd();
```

Hope to help this